# Press Android Back button with appium in -no-window mode

Tags: android, appium, back-button

I'm starting the android emulator with `emulator.exe -no-window` and trying to send the appium command `driver.PressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.Back)`. Unfortunately nothing happens. I assume the emulator doesn't support the back button in headless mode. If I start the emulator without -no-window then the back button works.

Is there a way to work around this? Running the emulator with UI doesn't seem like a good idea on a CI build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The back button is available in headless mode. The issue itself was a timing problem - the button was clicked too early and therefore had no effect.